Using 何 to mean "many"?
I have doubts with the meaning of 何十回何百回 in this panel from Kakegurui chapter 4:

This sentence doesn't look like a question to me, so it doesn't make sense to interpret it as "how many tens of times and hundreds of times." I think it is understood as "many tens of times and hundreds of times." In this case, shouldn't it be 何十回も何百回も or maybe 何十回何百回と?
I cannot find any reference in any dictionary including this one, where 何 can mean "many." However, I noticed that the word 何回 has its own entry. One of its definitions is 多くの回数, which seems appropriate for the sentence in question, but I am not too sure because the provided example sentences show that 何回 used in this sense is paired with も. It makes me wonder if も is necessary.
Edit: I found this blog (?) post that discusses the difference between 何百回 and 数百回.

私の語感によると、「数百回」は「２００～４００回くらい」、「何百回」は、「百回」が1セットとして、それを繰り返すような感じ。少なくとも5セット以上。つまり５００～９００回くらいの感じでしょうか。


Like you said, either と or も would be necessary if this were a perfectly normal-looking piece of prose. However, there's an ellipsis after 何十回何百回, which makes this phrase somewhat "detached" from the surrounding text, allowing you to appreciate the sentence using the pattern of poems or lyrics. I mean, the following texts might seem "disorganized" or "fragmentary" if interpreted as normal prose, but they look perfect as poetry or lyrics, right?

Moon river, wider than a mile, I'm crossing you in style someday.
Are you going to Scarborough Fair? Parsley, sage, rosemary, and thyme.
Old pond, frogs jumped in, sound of water.

Similarly, the ellipsis and the lack of the particle add a certain rhythm and aesthetic quality to the sentence. I'd say the sentence looks all the more impressive because of the "pause" created by them. A technique like this isn't necessary in academic writing, but it is preferable in speeches to impress others.

Thanks! It seems like you are talking about anacoluthon?

@JohnDavies The sentence isn't incoherent enough to use such a word, but there's indeed some sort of "small interruption".

Yes. 何（なん）does mean many.
According to Wiktionary, 何 can be used as a prefix to other counters to mean many , especially when used with も. I see the も as implied in the manga snippet above after the ellipses. Something like 何十回何百回も。
It seems that you can leave it out and it's understood.
何回ドイツへ行きました。
But usually there otherwise.
何度もやってできない。
Here it's just a fancy a way to say, a lot of times. (probably in contrast to the previous sentence which goes 一回一回)

I don't think there's contrast. 一回一回 here is understood as "each and every."

You're right. I suppose I more specifically meant that contrast in semantics but similarity in syntax. Karl notices this as well and elaborates on that end.

I didn't try to translate the whole thing, so I may have misunderstood the intended rhetorical effect of using those two phrases. But it seems clear to me that it is an intentional rhetorical device.


This sentence doesn't look like a question to me, so it doesn't make sense to interpret it as "how many tens of times and hundreds of times." I think it is understood as "many tens of times and hundreds of times."

The problem is that you are thinking in terms of a Western (English, Romance language etc.) distinction between questions and ordinary statements. 何 is a generic marker for an unknown thing (or value); context determines whether the subtext is "I want you to tell me what goes here" or "the thing that goes here isn't particularly relevant". It's the same as how か is a marker for "the preceding bit was doubtful/uncertain", which is how it can be used both for yes/no questions ("I want you to tell me whether this actually is the case") and making lists with archetypal rather than specific values ("there could be this, and (と) - oh, it's only something like that (か) - something like that...").
So when it takes the place where a number - rather, a digit - would normally appear, the idea is simply that the exact value isn't determined. Context determines whether the listener is expected to provide one, or the speaker is simply eliding that detail.
So it's not so much that 何 "means 'many'", but rather 何十 is "tens" (unspecific number of tens), 何百 is "hundreds" etc.
But yes, 何十回何百回 is clearly being contrasted with the previous 一回一回. "Tens and hundreds of times" (i.e. becoming habitual over time), as opposed to "once and once" (i.e., "now and again").
There's no と because they aren't two separate quantities (and it would have to go in between anyway). It's not "tens of times, and also hundreds of times".
There's no も because the overall sentence isn't about how something wouldn't change even with the large number of times gambling - rather, it's contrastive (as established already). It's not that the number of times is irrelevant to the outcome, but rather, that it's irrelevant to making the point.

Hmm, do you have any example sentences where 何 can be ambiguous?
